# How to get token metadata?

Tags: spl-token, token, metadata

Since `@solana/spl-token-registry` package is deprecated, I have the question: how to get token metadata by contract address?

- decimals - can be obtained by `getParsedAccountInfo` method of `@solana/web3.js` library.
- symbol - ?
- token name -?

Is there any API to get symbol and token name?

For example the following token not present in the `@solana/spl-token-registry` https://solscan.io/token/hntyVP6YFm1Hg25TN9WGLqM12b8TQmcknKrdu1oxWux

Related issue: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/4144

Answer (score 5):

Token Registry is an outdated way to retrieve token's metadata. The current standard is to use Metaplex's Token Metadata Program to add on-chain metadata for tokens.

First, you need to calculate the metadata address of the token, which can be done using `@metaplex-foundation/js` lib like this:

```
import { Metaplex } from '@metaplex-foundation/js';

const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection);
const metadataPda = metaplex.nfts().pdas().metadata({ mint: mintAddress });
```

`connection` is a `Connection` instance from web3.js library and `mintAddress` is the public key of the token's mint.

Alternatively, you can also calculate pda directly using `@solana/web3.js` lib using seeds.

Once you have the PDA, fetch the token's metadata like this:

```
import { Metadata } from "@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata";

const account = await Metadata.fromAccountAddress(connection, metadataPda);
```

It will return `Metadata` class and you can get details about the token name, symbol, etc using `data` property on account: `account.data.name`.

More about `Metadata`:https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/classes/Metadata.html

Comment: Thank you. I've faced with that it is impossible to get metadata for some old tokens, for example 7i5KKsX2weiTkry7jA4ZwSuXGhs5eJBEjY8vVxR4pfRx